# PHP File Upload not able to move files from Temp

Tags: php, html, image-uploading

When I try to use `move_uploaded_file()` in the `upload.php` script, it just returns the programmed error "An error occurred somewhere. Try again or contact the admin.", It's failing at moving the file it seems. I cannot seem to trace the problem, I made sure the form had all the essential parts like `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and such, and everything works up until it tries to move the file from the tmp directory to the uploads directory. Any insights?

console.php

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">
  <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-grid-a">
    <li><label for="admin">Posting As:</label><input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>" name="admin" disabled></li>
    <li><label for="title">Post Title:</label><input type="text" name="title"></li>
    <li><label for="body">Post Body:</label><textarea name="body" placeholder="Type your post here. Feel free to use HTML!"></textarea></li>
    <li><label for="myfile">Upload Post Image:</label><input type="file" accept="image/*" id="myfile" name="myfile"></li>
    <li><input type="submit" id="submitPost" name="submitPost" value="SUBMIT"></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

upload.php

```php
<?php
    $currentDir = getcwd();
    $uploadDirectory = "./uploads/";

    $errors = []; // Store all foreseen and unforseen errors here

    $fileExtensions = ['jpeg','jpg','png','gif','svg']; // Get all the file extensions

    $fileName = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
    $fileTmpName  = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
    $fileExtension = strtolower(end(explode('.',$fileName)));

    $uploadPath = $currentDir . $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName); 

    if (isset($_POST['submitPost'])) {

        if (! in_array($fileExtension,$fileExtensions)) {
            $errors[] = "This file extension is not allowed. Please upload a JPEG, JPG, GIF or PNG file";
        }

        if ($fileSize > 2000000) {
            $errors[] = "This file is more than 2MB. Sorry, it has to be less than or equal to 2MB";
        }

        if (empty($errors)) {

            $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadPath);

            if ($didUpload) {
                echo "The file " . basename($fileName) . " has been uploaded";
            } else {
                echo "An error occurred somewhere. Try again or contact the admin";
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                echo "These are the errors" . "\n" . $error;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: what do you get when you print out $uploadPath?

Comment: `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs./uploads/americanflag.png` is what I get when printed, for example

Comment: I should add that I tried removing the `.` before `/uploads/` as well but no avail

Answer (score 1):

First check the destination path do exists and then check the destination path or folder has read and write permission to it.

Comment: This should have been a comment

Comment: Just what I had in mind.. Could you improve the quality of your answer by adding on how to do so

Comment: I know the path exists but I don't know how to check read/write privs with AWS Lightsail running LAMP 7

Comment: I tried `chmod -R 755 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/` and it registered in SSH, but didn't fix the issue

Comment: I used `chmod -R 777 /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/` and it works now

Comment: @MatthewWalker Use `chmod()` to change permissions of the folder and its sub folder too. A good permission would be `0655`

Answer (score 1):

This could be an permission issue. You can check if the directory exists and is writable.

```
if (empty($errors)) {

  if(!is_dir($uploadPath)){
    mkdir($uploadPath, 0655);
  }

  if(!is_writable($upload_path)){
    chmod($upload_path, 0655); // Note 0655 is not a string but an int
  }

  // ... Rest of code ...
```